# Scala Future.sequence(Iterator) throws NoSuchElementException

Tags: scala

Why is the following code throwing `java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator`???

```
     implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.global
     val it = (0 until 10).toIterator.map{
       x =>
         Thread.sleep(500)
         println(x)
         x
     }
     val it2 = new Iterator[Future[Int]] {
       def hasNext = it.hasNext
       def next() = Future { blocking { it.next() } }
     } //This should be equivalent to it.map{x => Future{blocking{x}}}
     Await.result(Future.sequence(it2), Inf)
```

Subsidiary question: why is `it2` not behaving as `it.map{x => Future{blocking{x}}}` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a concurrency error, someone calls `hasNext` it returns `true` because the underlying iterator is capable of producing new elements. Then it calls `next` this returns a future that when completed will hold the `next` value.
However, for the caller *(in this case `Future.sequence`)* it already finished so it calls `hasNext` again which will return `true` again but because the underlying iterator hasn't finished producing the first element so we produce a second that is enqueued until the first one finish *(so you win nothing with the future)*.

And this continues creating more and more and more futures that will eventually call `next` and get a `NoSuchElementException` because the underlying iterator didn't have more elements but you already create more and more futures waiting for more and more elements.
So, in other words, you are getting a `true` in `hasNext` just because it hasn't finished producing elements and as such haven't mutated its internal state; not because it actually has more elements.

This is a good recordatory that mutability + concurrency = headaches.
Again, I recommend you to use an appropriate abstraction for thi

Comment: By adding some printouts in my `next` and `hasNext` methods I could see the issue: `Future.sequence` is calling them more than what the iterator contains. Actually running `it2.size` returned 163... So you are right, it is a concurrency issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is pointing to the right direction, but I just rephrase it a bit more cleanly. By adding some printouts in `next()` and `hasNext` methods, one can see that they are called continuously. This is because the `it` and `it2` gets out-of-sync: `it.next()` is blocking, while `it2.next()` is not, but `it2.hasNext == it.hasNext`, so `it2.hasNext` is blocking. As a result `it2` has its `next()` and `hasNext` out-of-sync which is a mess!